# How do I save an array index tuple in R?

Tags: r

I am manipulating arrays in R by looping over their dimensions, for example like this:

```
arr <- array(runif(6), dim=c(2,3))
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    arr[i, j] <- arr[i, j] + 1
  }
}
```

In my application I have many dimensions, and multiple arrays to manipulate in the inner loop (with more complicated manipulation than adding 1). In order to make the code more readable, I would like to somehow save the tuple `[i, j]` in an object, say `idx`, and then reuse `idx` to access the arrays. The following code does not work, but it describes best what I would like to achieve in the inner loop:

```
idx <- c(i, j)             # this is wrong
arr[idx] <- arr[idx] + 1
```

What should I put instead of `c(i, j)` above? Please keep in mind that I am actually working with more than 2 dimensions, e.g., `[i, j, k, l, m, n]`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky, but you can do it with `do.call` as long as you wrap both the array and the index in a list prior to combining them in to a bigger list.

```
arr <- array(1:8,dim=c(2,2,2))
idx <- list(1,1,1)
do.call("[",c(list(arr),idx))
[1] 1
do.call("[",c(list(arr),list(1,2,1)))
[1] 3
```